# How could I avoid diamond inheritance?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I am currently working on a C++ design where I have this inheritance structure:

```
  A
 / \
B   C
```

Class `A` does the computations that are common to both classes `B` and `C`, and classes `B` and `C` are two different ways of initializing `A`.

I'd like to add some sort of hybrid initialization, i.e. a class `D` that would use methods from `B` and `C`.

However, I'd need to use diamond inheritance to be able to access `B::init()` and `C::init()` to set up the attributes of `D`.

I know I can avoid diamond problems using virtual inheritance, but I get runtime errors that I don't have when I copy manually the methods. Moreover, I have problems when trying to instantiate the classes `B` and `C`, and a colleague advised me to never use diamond inheritance in my designs.

Therefore, I'd like to find some kind of "clean" workaround, which I have not been able to do.

- I could put all the initialization routines in class `A`, but for the moment they are separated nicely and I'd like to avoid having one big class where I can't really separate the distinct groups of functions of the classes `B` and `C`. EDIT after answer: This is what I chose, using different cpp files to split my "big" class into logical groups of methods.
- I could also remove the inheritance links and replace them with friendship, where the methods of `B` and `C` are static and work on a pointer of type `A*`. This way, I could call `B::init(A* a)` and `C::init(A* a)` from `D::init(A* a)`. However, I'd have to replace all the uses of `_fooAttribute` by `a->_fooAttribute`, which is a bit cumbersome and does not seem right.

What would you recommend ?

Comment: Is it possible for `D` to be composed of a `B` and a `C`, instead of being both? For example, you could have `class D { B b; C c; public: /* methods from B and C get exposed here * / };`

Comment: Yes, obviously, but let's say I want to initialize `d._myVector`, `b` and `c` would work on `b._myVector` and `c._myVector`, not on the one I want.

Comment: @pvallet At this point, you should probably post some relevant code so we can see what you're really trying to do. Many people have said that you don't seem to need inheritance, but you're insisting that you do. I really don't like the idea of initializing another class (B and C) from D using A. Unless you leave very good comments, your code will be very confusing.

Comment: @wandercoder Yes you're right, I was actually discussing it in the comments of the answer by shachar shemesh, I think I don't need inheritance. It was a way of making my code more modular but had no precise meaning.

Comment: 'a colleague advised me to never use diamond inheritance in my designs' - someone you'd better not take advices from. 'using virtual inheritance, but I get runtime errors' - what are these? we can hardly help you fix what we don't know about. Diamond inheritance is handled perfectly in C++, you couldn't wish for better: once you understood it, it works perfectly and actually *helps* your design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your design calls for diamond inheritance, then that is what you need to do. People treat it as a "must not use" feature of C++, but the truth of the matter is that it is there, it is fully defined (if somewhat complex to understand), and if your problem space calls for it, you should use it.

In particular, I was not able to understand whether this is, indeed, a diamond inheritance. In particular, does it make sense for the `A` inside `B` and the `A` inside `C` to be the same *instance* of `A`? From your question it would appear that it is not. That Both `B` and `C` has a certain, different, way it makes sense to initialize `A`. If that is the case, this is not a diamond inheritance. Just make sure that `B` and `C` inherit `A` in a non-virtual inheritance.

With that said, make sure this is, indeed, what your design calls for. Can you honestly say that `B` **is a** `A`? That `C`? Can you honestly say that `D` **is both** a `B` and a `C`? If not, maybe making `A` a member of `B`, `C` or both, or making `B` or `C` members of `D` would make more sense.

If the only reason you are inheriting from `A` is as a way to extend `A`'s provided methods, then consider simply making those methods a member of `A`. As stated above, while reducing code duplication is a worthy cause, the design should make sure that inheritance relationship is a *is a* relationship. Deviating from that is asking for trouble.

Comment: Basically, my initialization is filling an array of geometric primitives which is contained in `A`, and adjusting the other attributes. Let's say that `B` fills the array with triangles and `C` fills it with circles. A is a common interface to do computations on these primitives. `D` would be filling half my array with triangles, and half my array with circles, so it is at the same time a `B` and a `C`. The code is working when I copied the method manually, but somehow fails when using diamond inheritance, which somehow feels like the right way to do it...

Comment: @pvallet `B` fills **all of the array** with the **same type**. `C` fills **all of the array** with the **same type**, but different than the one `B` uses. `D` **fills all of the array** with **multiple types**. To me it sounds like `D` is different than `B` and `C` even though it may fill the array with the types used by `B` and `C`. Therefore, I'd ask why shouldn't `D`  directly inherit from `A`?

Comment: I agree, but I'd like to avoid duplicating the code of `B` and `C`, which I want to use in `D`

Comment: There is a reason why inheritance is described as a **is a** relationship. If you deviate from that premise, you are very likely to run into trouble down the road. It sounds to me like a design based on membership would work better for your problem.

Comment: @pvallet Your first comment says you should create `B`s or `C` and cast them to `A`s and use an array of `A`s. No need for `D` to even exist.

Comment: @pvallet You should not for inheritance just to avoid code duplication. Instead use inheritance they way you should. If there is code duplication factor it out so that unrelated classes can share it.

Comment: @JamesAdkison So would you recommend the first option, putting all the methods in the class `A` ? I guess I could separate the code in different .cpp files that all correspond to class `A` in order to organize my code.

Comment: @pvallet there is nothing wrong with having a class contain methods that it doesn't use itself, but are useful to any reasonable user of that class. With that said, please note that the semantics matter. You should not let a local need drive your design. The methods do need to make sense in the context in which they exist.

Comment: @pvallet Without fully knowing all the details of your specific issue, I'd say put functions in `A` that are expected to be useful to *all* derived classes. If this is not the case then hang the initialization functions somewhere else (e.g., free functions).

Comment: @ShacharShemesh @JamesAdkison The methods would all make sense in the context of `A`, as they are all ways to initialize it. There would be no problem with further inheritance, I would not need any inheritance anymore. It was a way to separate my code, but I think I'll do it only by putting the code in separate cpp files so that it would be more readable. Free functions is not very handy though as I explained in the second point of my question. Thank you

Comment: One of you should add an answer accounting for the discussion in the commentaries so I could give credit for it and mark the problem as "solved" :)

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance is an "is a" relationship. If B is an A, then you're good. The same applies to C. From your description, you do not have this relationship. Instead, you have a utility class (A) that does computations. You might want to make this have static methods as it shouldn't need to store any data in itself, if it's truly a utility. There's nothing wrong with passing A an instance of B or C and having it access the properties that it needs using B->fooAttribute. However, you will probably want both B and C to implement a common interface so you don't have to know which one you're looking at.

Comment: `A` precisely constitutes this common interface.

Comment: @pvallet An interface should generally be pure. Separate the utility and interface aspects of A into different types.